# Fitting a truncated binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

I have some data that I want to try fit a binomial distribution to. However, all the data for zero values is missing due to the data collection method.

Is there a function in `R` or `MATLAB` that can fit truncated binomial distributions?

For example,
If I had the following binomially distributed data:
`data = binornd(10,0.1,1,10^5);` and then removed all the zeros to get `truncated.data= data(data~=0);`

Is there a way to fit a binomial distribution to `truncated.data` that estimates the original binomial parameters `n=10` and `p=0.1`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a function? As far as I'm aware, both R and MATLAB comprise programming languages in which you can do the fit – or are you only interested in single function calls to existing functions in R or MATLAB?

Comment: By function, I mean something like MLE in MATLAB but I would like to tell the function that the data for zero is missing.